# how can i get access path of form in AX2012?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to get access path of form like shown in the address bar of workspace , or like shown in the help file of form  using x++.

thank's in advance

Comment: I don't think you can, at least I don't know of a way. It's probably all kernel code. Are you're trying to auto generate help files or are you doing something else? More info might help us provide an alternative. You could use the menus in the AOT to build that path but then again a menu item can be started from multiple locations.

Comment: YEs i try to create a class that can generate a help file, i use the path po menu item ( dispay and output), than i research by the property - name of orm  of the menu item, than i can get the name of the menu item, for the tasks taht use the form , i don't find any idea to get , it's so diffucult to do that, have to serch in the Menu node ( any way) , tis just an idea

Comment: I'm not sure what you hope to achieve by auto generating help files actually. Maybe I'm missing something but the user can view all labels and help labels in their client. I think having less help files with useful info written by a consultant or developer is better than a whole lot of generated content, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can get the current path in the breadcrumb, I don't know of a way. But you could lookup all instances where your menu item is used using the crossref. It requires the cross reference to be up to date but that shouldn't be a problem because you will only have to run this once.

The following job constructs the paths by which the customer listpage can be opened:
    static void JobXrefBC(Args _args)
    {
        #TreeNodeSysNodeType
        #Properties
        #AOT
        TreeNode menuItemNode = TreeNode::findNode(@"\Menu Items\Display\CustTableListPage");
        TreeNode menuNode;
        xRefPaths xRefPaths;
        xRefReferences xRefReferences;
        TreeNode parentNode;
        Str path;

```
    if(menuItemNode)
    {
        xRefPaths = xRefPaths::find(menuItemNode.treeNodePath());

        while select xRefReferences
            where xRefReferences.referencePathRecId == xRefPaths.RecId
            && xRefReferences.Reference == XRefReference::Read
        {
            path = SysLabel::labelId2String(menuItemNode.AOTgetProperty(#PropertyLabel));

            menuNode = TreeNode::findNode(xRefPaths::findRecId(xRefReferences.xRefPathRecId).Path);

            if(menuNode && SysTreeNode::path2ApplObjectType(menuNode.treeNodePath()) == UtilElementType::Menu)
            {
                parentNode = menuNode.AOTparent();

                while(parentNode && parentNode.treeNodePath() != #MenusPath)
                {
                    path = SysLabel::labelId2String(parentNode.AOTgetProperty(#PropertyLabel))  + " > " + path;
                    parentNode = parentNode.AOTparent();
                }

                info(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Accounts receivable > Common > Customers > All customers
Sales and marketing > Common > Customers > All customers
```